# Change icon image size on SweetAlert

Tags: css, image, icons, size, alert

I'm trying for change icon image size on SweetAlert.
In the .css file I see:

```
.sweet-alert .sa-icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: content-box; }
```

I have changed this values:

```
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
```

But not change nothing. My .png file is showed in a predefinite size. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

use the "imageSize" object class in your controller.

```
  swal({  title: "Oops...",
          text: "Please have a title and body in your post.",
          imageUrl: "../../../img/oopsface.png",
          imageSize: '600x600'
  });
```

(if you want to modify your sweet alert in this way, you need to use this formatting to call the alert)

Answer (score 3):

> 'imageHeight' for image height and 'imageWidth' for image width

```
swal({        
    title: 'Alert!',        
    text: 'Content',        
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/user.png',        
    imageHeight: 80, 
    imageWidth: 80,       
    imageClass:'img-responsive rounded-circle',        
    animation: false        
});
```

1. 'title' for alert title
2. 'text' for alert content
3. 'imageUrl' for embed image url from website
4. 'imageHeight' for image size(height)
5. 'imageWidth' for image size(width)
6. 'imageClass' for your custom image class/other class added

HTML Output like

> `<img src="assets/images/user.png" class="img-responsive rounded-circle" height="80" width="80" >`

Answer (score 1):

for current versions, what is mentioned no longer works, for buttons and image

taste this

```
swal({
      title: "Search...",
      text: "please, wait",
      icon: "../../images/gif/blue.gif",
      buttons: false,
      closeOnClickOutside: false
    });
```

and this

```
.swal-icon img{
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Try removing .sa-icon.

```css
.sweet-alert  {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: content-box; }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="sweet-alert">
```

Comment: I use imageUrl:'.png' for add my image to SweetAlert. I must only delete .sa-icon? But the problem is the size.

Comment: Can't you just change the img src?

Comment: I not use img scr. My syntax is with imageURL because I have set also other parameters. The only problem is the size of my image. I tried, if I deleted sa-icon the alert not is showed.

Comment: Deleted sa-icon and add img src, alert not is showed.

Comment: I have deleted sa-icon and replace the css with original. Add <img src="dist/image.png" class="sweet-alert"> but Alert not open.

Comment: I use this code:          <script type="text/javascript">
sweetAlert({   title: "ADULT CONTENT",   text: "ARE YOU OVER 18?",  imageUrl: "dist/image.png", showCancelButton: true,  cancelButtonText: "No",  confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000", confirmButtonText: "Yes, I'am Over 18", closeOnConfirm: true },
  function(isConfirm){
   if (isConfirm) {   
   } else {  window.location.href = 'http://'; } });
</script>       With this works all, only the size of my image the problem. I'm using Mihalism Multi Host and editing a .tpl page.

Comment: News about my problem? Let me know, please. Thanks Kadeem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
swal({
  title: "Oops...",
  text: "Please have a title and body in your post.",
  imageUrl: "../../../img/oopsface.png",
  //instead of imageSize use imageWidth and imageHeight
  imageWidth: 600,
  imageHeight: 600,
});
```

Comment: generates error in preview, not working

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my `img` class was overwriting `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`. For solving this I had to add a custom class on the swal init like this:

```
swal({
    title: "Title",
    text: "Swal text",
    imageUrl: "/example/image.png",
    imageClass: "contact-form-image",
    confirmButtonText:"Ok",
});
```

And define a the class on your style.css:

```
.contact-form-image {
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I FIND THIS TO SOLVE MY PROBLEM

```js
swal({
  title: "Oops...",
  text: "Please have a title and body in your post.",
  imageUrl: "../../../img/oopsface.png",
  //instead of imageSize use imageWidth and imageHeight
  imageWidth: 600,
  imageHeight: 600,
});
```