# angular (js) alert with a large image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, alert

I have a project which involves crowdsourcing elements.
As part of that, I would like it when a user enters a specific html page, that they will be prompted with a nice alert, with a "large" (Hi-Def, nice detail) image, a question below it, and a "Yes"/"No" choice.

I have reviewed [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) for this, but the images are very small and unclear in it:
[image: Example of what I see when I use SweetAlert with my image]

Is there any way to use SweetAlert with a larger image, or a different solution to this problem?

Comment: have you considered using a modal, it'll be more elegant than an alert box.

Comment: Just use few lines of custom CSS styles .

Comment: Where would I go about to change the CSS of sweetalert?
It doesn't seem like a trivial task like described..

Comment: Okay thanks for your help everyone.
I found an answer in another discussion:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238017/change-icon-image-size-on-sweetalert) Apparently it's just a matter of CSS tampering like you said.